# Expo Image Picker not displaying all albums

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am using Expo Image Picker in my React Native project to allow users to pick images from their device's gallery. However, I've noticed that it doesn't display all the albums available on the device, only a subset of them. How can I make it show all the albums, including those that are not currently being displayed?

Here's the code snippet I'm using for the Expo Image Picker:

```
const addimage = async () => {
    
    
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      const image = { uri: result.uri, name: result.uri.split('/').pop(), type: "image/jpeg" }
      const FromData = new FormData();
      FromData.append('image', image)
      const obj = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }

      const newassets = { ...assets.find(item => item._id === props.data._id), image: [...assets.find(item => item._id === props.data._id).image, image.name] }
      dispatch(updateAsset1({ assets: newassets }))
      await axios.post(`http://141.226.241.38:3001/assets/uplaod/${props.data._id}`, FromData, obj)
    }


  }
```

I've explored the Expo Image Picker documentation and searched for related issues on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found a solution that allows me to access all albums.